# Use of dcopula.t with a vector in R QRM, Error in apply...dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r

How can I use the copula density function `dcopula.t()` with a vector?

Modifying the example from the docs it get the error `Error in apply(Udata, 2, qt, df = df) : must have a positive length`. Applying it on the whole matrix works, allthough the docs demands a vector. See my example below:

```
library("QRM", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
#Modified Example from the docs
S <- equicorr(d = 6, rho = 0.7)
data <- rcopula.t(2000, df = 4, Sigma = S)

dcopula.t(data[1,], Sigma = S, df=4)
#Get error: Error in apply(Udata, 2, qt, df = df) : must have a positive length
is.vector(data[1,]) #True

#this works
dcopula.t(data, Sigma = S, df=4)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Using `dcopula.t(data[1:2,], Sigma = S, df=4)` works. So, apparently,  you can't pass a single vector into a copula. I haven't used copulas for a long time, but I remember it has a lot to do with correlations between vectors. If there is only one vector, you can't have a correlation between vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `copula::dCopula()`. All what you need is:

```
Library(copula)
Dens.t<- dCopula()
```

There are some examples provided in the manual description of the package.